# Why does strsplit return a list

Tags: regex, r, parsing, strsplit

Consider

```
text <- "who let the dogs out"
fooo <- strsplit(text, " ")
fooo
[[1]]
[1] "who"  "let"  "the"  "dogs" "out"
```

the output of `strsplit` is a list. The list's first element then is a vector, that contains the words above.

Why does the function behave that way? Is there any case in which it would return a list with more than one element?

And I can access the words using

```
fooo[[1]][1]
[1] "who"
```

, but is there no simpler way?

Comment: Because that's the way it was written

Comment: That's an answer any religious fundamentalist would have been proud of: "because HE made it so".

Comment: Well if you had two elements in `text`, and `strsplit` returned a vector, how would you distinguish which splits came from which element in `text`?

Comment: with your example, `unlist(fooo)[1]` is an alternative to `fooo[[1]][1]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To your first question, one reason that comes to mind is so that it can keep different length result vectors in the same object, since it is vectorized over `x`:

```
text <- "who let the dogs out"
vtext <- c(text, "who let the")
##
> strsplit(text, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "who"  "let"  "the"  "dogs" "out" 

> strsplit(vtext, " ")
[[1]]
[1] "who"  "let"  "the"  "dogs" "out" 

[[2]]
[1] "who" "let" "the"
```

If this were to be returned as a `data.frame`, `matrix`, etc... instead of a `list`, it would have to be padded with additional elements.

Comment: Right, I thought about a vector in `y`, not in `x`. Great. But I'm so tempted to change your `vtext` to `...c(text, 'who who who')

Comment: Also, there are functions in other packages such as `stringr` and `stringi` that have the capability of returning something other than a `list`, such as a character matrix (provided the resulting vectors are the same length, presumably). I haven't had a chance to spend much time using `stringi` yet, but it seems to have several string splitting functions that would be potentially useful to you (check the [see also section here](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stri_split.html))

Comment: `stringi::stri_list2matrix` is awesome